# Dynamic automation scheduling in Toad

Tags: sql, automation, toad, toad-scripting

I have been following Stackoverflow for years but posting for the first time. I am trying to dynamically schedule a script in Toad but there doesn't seem to be an option for it. For example, I want to automatically trigger a script on lets say 2nd Feb, 2020. Then it should run after 4 weeks on 1st March 2020. Then after 5 weeks on 5th April, 2020. Then after 4 weeks on 3rd May, 2020 and so on. Is there a way of achieving this in Toad automation?

TIA

Comment: What have you tried? What do you have? What are your _exact_ issues with what you _have_. SO is not a code generation service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use TOAD as a GUI to access Oracle database(s). I don't know which database you use. Nonetheless, from my point of view, you should schedule a **database job**.

In Oracle, you'd use `DBMS_JOB` or `DBMS_SCHEDULER`. The latter is capable of running even an operating system script (if that's a "script" you are talking about). Otherwise, usually we schedule a stored procedure (which resides in the database).

If, on the other hand, you'd want to run that "script" on the operating system level only, then check your **operating system scheduling capabilities**. On MS Windows, that would be the Task Scheduler; on UNIX, it is cron.

As intervals you'd want to run that script isn't *straightforward* (e.g. "on 2nd of every month" or "every 5 weeks" and similar) but "today, 4 weeks later, 5 weeks later, 4 weeks later, 5 weeks later, ...", you'll probably have to develop some logic to do so. For example, create a calendar table and mark days on which you want to run that script, schedule it to run *daily* but check whether today's data equals the one which is marked. Or, create two jobs: one that starts "today" and runs every 10 weeks, and the one that starts "today + 4 weeks" and runs every 10 weeks.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. I am using Toad to access Microsoft SQL Server database. Also, can you please give some more info on how to schedule TOAD scripts on MS operating system. I am sorry if this is a stupid question. I am new to all this

Comment: I don't use MS SQL Server and I don't know its scheduling capabilities. As of MS Windows, as I said - it is Task Scheduler you'd use. On the other hand, I don't use "TOAD scripts" so I can't tell how to schedule them. What are they?